Middleware inheritance in mounted FastAPI SubAPI's
The project I'm working on has grown to the point one massive API doesn't suffice, so I have split it into sub applications.
To ensure this refactor goes well, I wanted to test if and how middleware is inherited across parent/daughter applications.
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
app = FastAPI()
subapi = FastAPI()

@app.get("/app")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World from main app"}

@subapi.get("/sub")
def read_sub():
    return {"message": "Hello World from sub API"}

app.mount("/subapi", subapi)

@app.middleware("http")
async def say_hi(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    print('Middleware Triggered')
    return response


Now, after starting the app: uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080) and accessing the the docs of app and the subapi, I obtain the following logs:
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57079 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Middleware Triggered
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57079 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Middleware Triggered
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57079 - "GET /subapi/docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Middleware Triggered
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57079 - "GET /subapi/openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Case closed, middleware is inherited from the parent app, so if I want to add middleware to all sub apps, I should simply add it once to the parent app, or so I thought.
Think again. This quite explicitly contradicts the independence the docs note, as well as the most notable discussion on SO.
When printing the app/subapi's middleware as follows, we confirm subapi does not have the middleware attached:
print(app.__dict__)
print(subapi.__dict__)

>>> {..., 'user_middleware': [Middleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware, dispatch=<function say_hi at 0x00000191337C0E00>)], 'middleware_stack': None}
>>> {..., 'user_middleware': [], 'middleware_stack': None}

Which aligns with previous answers and the documentation, as expected.
Questions:

Why is the main app's middleware still triggered by requests to the SubAPI when it is not explicitly attached to subapi?
What does it mean for middleware to 'not be inherited' in this context, as its triggered either way?

If I understand the situation correctly, the answer to question 1 is fairly straight forward:
While the middleware is not directly associated with the SubAPI, it still gets triggered due to the routing structure - as the SubAPI's route contains the main app's route. This does still leave question 2.

I'm familiar with routers and am already using them widely in my full application. My original explicit need to use sub-apps came from requiring different sets of docs, so I don't believe they would suffice for my purposes.

You could always perform a check on the URL path within the middleware and proceed as desired. Related answers to this approach could be found here and here, as well as here and here.

Question 1:
The main app's middleware still triggered by requests to the SubAPI because of the way the mounting mechanism is implemented.
Having these chain of inheritances:
APIRoute -> Route -> BaseRoute
Mount -> BaseRoute

You can see that at the end of the day, they both can be seen as "routes" from FastAPI's point of view.
When a subapi is mounted, a Mount() object is created and added to the .routes list(where the APIRoute are added too):
(link)
    def mount(self, path: str, app: ASGIApp, name: str | None = None) -> None:
        route = Mount(path, app=app, name=name)
        self.routes.append(route)

And as you already know, the middlewares are executed before handling the routes.
